# Spring MVC Project unable to load log4j.xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, log4j

I was having some problem when trying to load the log4j2.xml into my Spring MVC project. Here is my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mybatis.xml, /WEB-INF/log4j2.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<!-- Spring MVC Servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then my log4j2.xml which is placed under `/WEB-INF/` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="DEBUG">
<Appenders>
    <Console name="LogToConsole" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout
            pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <!-- avoid duplicated logs with additivity=false -->
    <Logger name="com.example" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
    </Logger>
    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="LogToConsole" />
    </Root>
</Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However, I am getting these error messages:

```
Jul 03, 2020 2:33:39 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Jul 03, 2020 2:33:39 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 31; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Configuration'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:637)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:251)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:204)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:189)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1921)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3101)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1843)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:884)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:233)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:228)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:78)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:151)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 31; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Configuration'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1901)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:741)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3132)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:852)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilder.parse(RegistryDocumentBuilder.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:430)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 61 more
```

I imported log4j-api-2.13.3.jar, log4j-core-2.11.0.jar and slf4j-log4j12-2.0.0.jar into my project. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Two things, why not use the application.properties and just use logging.level.com.your.package=debug. The other one is that the log4j2 file does not go in WEB-INFO it goes in src/main/resources or src/main/java otherwise you have to define the path in the argument when starting the jvm. This can help: https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-log4j-2-example/

Comment: My project structure does not have the resource folder. Its only src and WebContent -> WEB-INF

Comment: Maybe read the entire comment I wrote? " it goes in src/main/resources or src/main/java otherwise you have to define the path in the argument when starting the jvm". See you didn't read this at all as you marked just that as the answer..

Answer (score 0):

Error shows that **logaj2.xml** is in wrong path:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 2 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/log4j2.xml] is invalid;
```

So change the path of **log4j2.xml** file as `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`.

Hope This Help!!

Answer (score 0):

You have configured your webapp with

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-mybatis.xml, /WEB-INF/log4j2.xml
  </param-value>
</context-param>
```

The contextConfigLocation parameter is how you tell Spring where to find its configuration files.  Spring simply doesn't understand how to interpret the log4j configuration file you have passed it.

You need to follow the directions in the [Log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) to configure Log4j.

Comment: Hi my project is dynamic web project. May I know where should I place the log4j2.xml?

Comment: What do you mean by “dynamic web project”?

Comment: As in when I create the project, I selected dynamic web project. My project folder structure only have the src and WEB-INF

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't have anything called a "dynamic web project" that I can see.  I see documentation for Eclipse but since I don't use that I can't tell you what the directory structure looks like, what Eclipse will put on the classpath. But you will want the log4j2.xml file to end up in the classes directory.

Comment: I am using Eclipse. My folder structure from root is src/sc/project which contains all Java classes, WebContent/WEB-INF/... which contains all xml files. When I put the log4j2 under src/sc/project folder, it works, but the structure is just very wrong. Do you have any ideas how to wired the log4j2 to read from WebContent/WEB-INF/.. ?

Comment: The WEB-INF directory isn't on the class path in a web application.  I only use the "normal" Maven layout where the file would go in src/main/resources. I can't really help with anything specific to Eclipse.  But the end result is for any web app the file needs to be in WEB-INF/classes.

Comment: Alright thanks! Mine is not Maven project, its just normal Java project

Comment: LOL. To me a Maven project is a "normal" Java project. What you have is something specific to Eclipse.